# GSM Shield with Raspberry Pi Port Open

Tags: raspberry-pi, port, gsm

I have connected a-gsm shield http://itbrainpower.net/a-gsm/downloadables/a-gsm-series-presentation-v1.01.pdf with Raspberry Pi 3.
I have imported and attempted to execute power on code http://itbrainpower.net/a-gsm/RaspberryPI-gsm-shield-library-powerOnOff-demo-code-a-gsm. However, I am getting the following error message:

```
sudo ./poweronoff.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./poweronoff.py", line 66, in <module>
agsm.open()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 271, in open
raise SerialException("Port is already open.")
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Port is already open.
```

I assume I need to open a different port. If that is the solution, how do I do it. If that is not the solution, what do I need to do to satisfy this error message?

Answer (score 0):

Follow directions in this post https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?uid=195125&f=28&t=165897&start=0.

Basically, "enable_uart=1" should be the last line in '/boot/config.txt' for serial port operations.  Reboot the RPi3 and everything should work.